# litteral ${} and {{ }} in jquery templates

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-templates

Using [JQuery templates](http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/), what is the best way to output literal `${}` and `{{ }}` strings?
I need this because I would like to write templates that themselves generate other templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure of your exact needs, but if you are, for whatever reason, not able to use nested templates, then how about as a workaround either something like:

```
<script id="options" type="text/html">
        $&#123;test&#125;
</script>
```

or

```
<script id="options" type="text/html">
        ${writeVariable('test')}
</script>
```

with writeVariable (and other helpers or a more generic/advanced version of this one) defined elsewhere:

```
function writeVariable(varName) {
    return "${" + varName + "}";   
}
```

I did see reference in another post to a {#literal} tag, but I don't see that available anywhere in recent jquery.tmpl.js code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want to write ${} and {{}} as literals. I think you want to use nested templates: http://api.jquery.com/template-tag-tmpl/

Comment: I want to make templates that generate other templates. I don't think it's possible using nested templates, unless there is a way to "partially"  evaluate the template. (meaning that some nested templates remain unevaluated until some more data is available). In jTemplates there is {#literal} for this, so I thought maybe there was something similar in the official jquery templates plugin.